# How to write user-defined int with str in one print statement in python

Tags: python, pycharm, concatenation, user-defined-functions, calculator

So I'm making a basic table generator that will take a number from the user and print the table using for loop using the range function:

```
n = int(input('Enter number for table'))
for i in range(1,11):
    # print(n*i, '\n')
    print(n + "" + i + "=" + n*i)
```

I want the table to be printed in the following format:

e.g: `5*4=20`

I'm writing `print(n + "*" + i + "=" + n*i)`.

Here `n` is the user given number for which table is required and `i` is from for loop but the program returns an error saying can not concatenate str and int.

I'm new to python I'm coming from C++ it was easy in C++ to write these sorts of statements but I don't know how to do it in python.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate `strings` with `integers` or `floats`. Either converting the `int/float` to `string` or using a `,` instead of `+` would work.

1. `print(n , "*" , i , "=" , n*i)` # Also adds a space between elements.
   Or
2. `print(str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=" + str(n*i))`

Comment: Or use a formatted string literal like we do in 2022 and be done with it :-) `print(f"{n} * {i} = {n*i})"`